# WordPress private exploit?

Tags: web-application, php, exploit, wordpress

I have a friend who said he has a private exploit for all WordPress ran websites. I asked him to take down my private blog, to see if it is real. He couldn't do it. I tried to get some more information regarding it from him, and I did manage to do so.

He says it does deal with wp-config. I asked if he has to deal with the Auth Keys, which most people do not change, and he said no. Then I asked about plugins, because I am running none on this blog. He said no again.

Then I tried to see how "real" of a threat his claim is. I said "Why don't you take down a well known website running WordPress, if you know your private exploit is going to work" [Basically, with that question, I tried to see how much bullcrap he could talk about going after a target that matters when it comes to eFame]

Is there a known exploit that is public or 'private' currently available to take down a WordPress Site with only running the core web application? How secure is WordPress right now without plugins? Or is he a Script Kiddy?

Comment: There are exploits out there for pretty much everything, zero days. It just depends on if someone feels like the reason is good enough to use it, because they can be rare. He sounds like what some might call a "script kiddie."... or someone who knows nothing at all and wants to sound like a 1337 h4xx0r

Comment: First of all he's a script kiddie since WordPress isn't a webapp launched yesterday. The whole community is working to make it better. Now the only point is that WordPress sites get compromised because of misconfigured servers wherein an attackers might be able to carry out a SymLink Attack and then take it down.

Comment: If such a severe vulnerability was public, the WordPress developers would have done everything to publish a patch or new version in which the vulnerability would have been fixed. So either he has knowledge of an yet publicly unknown vulnerability, or he’s lying.

Comment: This is blatantly untrue. Wordpress like any other software out there has vulnerabilities. misconfigured servers definitely isn't the only way Wordpress sites get owned.

Comment: No, not really, Wordpress DOES make mistakes, have a look at Exploit-db and cvedetails. -1

Comment: Agreed but my point being that any vulnerability in wordpress can't lead to owning the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Private exploits** exist for many famous software out there, and the fact that a software is open-source, popular or many years old doesn't change a thing.

A vanilla Wordpress installation without additional modules is less likely to be exposed, but again, it is very possible that exploits exist for it.

Now, the question is more: does your friend have the technical skills needed to find this kind of vulnerabilities and exploit them?

Besides, asking him to "`take down a well known website running WordPress`" is **a very bad idea**, as this is illegal unless this website belongs to you or if you have a proper mandate to do so. If you want him to prove his point, you should install Wordpress on a server you own and authorize him to exploit it.